# Nifi ftp fails with path non-existent

Tags: apache-nifi

Using nifi ListFTP and GetFTP processors I can access remote ftp directories and files as expected, except for this path:

```
/Oa 45° 25t 32rn
```

I get a non-existent path error. Other paths with spaces work fine. (and other clients 'filezilla' work fine with this path.) However, Nifi does not. If it's the degree char °, how do I escape it? I've tried:

1. "/Oa 45° 25t 32rn"
2. '/Oa 45° 25t 32rn'
3. '"'/Oa 45° 25t 32rn'"'
4. /Oa\ 45°\ 25t\ 32rn
5. Oa%2045%C2%B0%2025t%2032rn (url encoding, trying it all)

Any ideas why this is failing and how to resolve? Thanks.

Comment: Note FEAT ftp response...
Command: FEAT
Response:  211-Features:
Response:   EPRT
Response:   EPSV
Response:   MDTM
Response:   PASV
Response:   REST STREAM
Response:   SIZE
Response:   TVFS
Response:   UTF8
Response:  211 End

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have an FTP server with a directory containing non-ASCII characters, so I cannot test this explicitly, but I would recommend using [UTF-8 Unicode encoding](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm) `0xC2B0` or `\uC2B0` to see if that works.

From [FileZilla Character Encoding](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Character_Encoding):

> The FTP protocol is specified in RFC 959, which was published in 1985.
>   The FTP protocol is designed on top of the original Telnet protocol,
>   which is specified in RFC 854. The relevant sections of the Telnet
>   specification regarding FTP are those covering the Network Virtual
>   Terminal (NVT). According to RFC 854, the NVT requires the use of
>   (7-bit) ASCII as the character set. Use of any other character set
>   requires explicit negotiation. This character set only contains 127
>   different characters: English letters and numbers, punctuation
>   characters and a few control characters. Accented letters, umlauts or
>   other scripts are not contained in the ASCII character set.
>
> In order to support non-English characters, the FTP specifications
>   were extended in 1999 in RFC 2640. This extension requires the use of
>   UTF-8 as the character set. This character set is a strict superset of
>   ASCII, every valid ASCII character is also the same character in
>   UTF-8. The UTF-8 character set can display any valid Unicode
>   character. That includes umlauts, accented letters and also different
>   scripts. This extension is fully backwards compatible with RFC 959.
>
> As long as you're using only English characters, it doesn't matter if
>   the software you are using supports RFC 2640 or not. However, if you
>   use non-English characters without using RFC 2640 compatible software,
>   there will be problems--problems which are entirely self-made by not
>   obeying the specifications.

Comment: Still fails...tried "/Oa 450xC2B0 25t 32rn" and "/Oa 45\uC2B0 25t 32rn". Note the edit that I can access this directory from filezilla but not using Nifi processor.